# Python parser XML to JSON - dictionary entries resolved as key-value pairs

Tags: python, json, xml, parsing

I have an xml in a given form

```
<parameters>
  <entry>
    <string>GAME_SRC</string>
    <string>some_url</string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>GAME_URL</string>
    <string>some_url2</string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>GAME_API_URL</string>
    <string>some_url_again</string>
  </entry>
  ...
</parameters>
```

which I want to transform to JSON.
What I succeeded so far is to get JSON to look like this:

```
"parameters": {
    "entry": [
      {
        "string": [
          "GAME_SRC",
          "some_url"
        ]
      },
      {
        "string": [
          "GAME_URL",
          "some_url2"
        ]
      },
      {
        "string": [
          "GAME_API_URL",
          "some_url_again"
        ]
      }
  ...
}
```

but this is not what I really want.
I need JSON to look like this

```
"parameters": {
    "GAME_SRC": "some_url",
    "GAME_URL": "some_url2",
    "GAME_API_URL": "some_url_again",
    ...
}
```

Is there any python XML parser that supports this out of the box? I tried a few libs like xmljson but so far no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I haven't found any lib that supports it out of the box, I wrote custom functions that skip certain XML tags and go deeper into XML structure, in order to get what I wanted.